# codigniter limit function not working with $this->db->query($sql)

Tags: codeigniter

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$subCatString', moto_type_id)";

    if($limit>0)
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }

    return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

codigniter limit function not working with $this->db->query($sql)

Comment: Yeap, it's not gonna work. `->query()` just execute sql query that you pass to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeap, it's not gonna work. `->query()` just execute sql query that you pass to it.

If you want to use `->limit()` do it like this:

```
$this->db
    ->from($this->table_name)
    ->where("FIND_IN_SET('".$subCatString."', moto_type_id)", NULL, FALSE);

if($limit>0)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
}

return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Remember to sanitize/escape $subCatString, because it will not be escaped by CI.